# Возвращаемый методом Messages.GetHistory() объект

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, vknet

```
        var t = vkClient.Messages.GetHistory(new MessagesGetHistoryParams()
        {
            UserId = memdersID[0],
            Count = 1,
            Offset = 0,
            StartMessageId = 0
        }).Messages.GetEnumerator().Current;
```

Почему коллекция `IEnumerator` является пустой, хотя сам возвращаемый `Messages.GetHistory()` объект сообщает, что должно быть 96 сообщений?
Как тогда получить объекты `Message` через метод `Messages.GetHistory()`?

Comment: Потому что после `GetEnumerator` надо `MoveNext` вызывать, чтобы получить `Current` для нулевого элемента. Замените `.GetEnumerator().Current` на `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: @aepot ничего не изменилось. `MoveNext()` возвращает `false`, будто итератор коллекции уже в конце, а `t.TotalCount` равен 96. С `FirstOnDefault()` он тоже `null`. Может что-то с VkApi?

Comment: В любом случае ваш вариант был нерабочий. Ну раз так, значит там действительно пусто.